# Resubmitting Google AdSense Application

Tags: google-adsense

I submitted an AdSense application, but I was disapproved. I have read over the email I was sent, which told me to visit http://www.google.com/adsense to resubmit my application.

When I visit http://www.google.com/adsense I am redirected to https://www.google.com/adsense/disapproved where I cannot do anything.

Clicking the *Return to AdSense home* link redirects me back to the same page.

[image: Screenshot of www.google.com/adsense/disapproved]

How can I resubmit my application?

Comment: Your only hope is to wait. There is a asynchronousy associated with Google adsense dispatching e-mails and the adsense account getting updated. In my case, my adsense account got updated before the email.

Comment: @RanaPrathap it's been three years since I received the e-mail.

Comment: Can't be done with the same account :/

Comment: @Analog are you sure about that? The email certainly seems to indicate that it is possible

Comment: I have unfortunately had this happen to me so while i can not speak to what Google states i can share my experience. But it does not matter in which manner your Adsense account was disabled (approval process / invalid clicks / risk to adwords advertisers ) it all seems to end with you being unable to log back into Adsense. The current Appeal forms Google offers all state "Please do not use this form if your account has never been an active AdSense account." You can try your luck with the Appeal troubleshooter - https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/1208722

Comment: Everything indicates that I *should* be able to resubmit: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/81904?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

[Visit this link](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=adsense&ltmpl=adsense&continue=https://support.google.com/adsense/contact/approvalstatus?hl=en&rd=2&rd=2&rd=3) and submit the details of your application. Google adsense staff will look at their records and e-mail you the status of your application.

Comment: I submitted the linked form and received a reply that my application has been fully reviewed, along with links to the AdSense help center, forum and blog.